# Rails, inheriting from abstract model does not keep attributes of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, abstract-class

I have created model by rails generator with some attributes then I made it abstract:

```
class AbstractModelClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Then I created new model with another attributes and inherited from above:

```
class Child < AbstractModelClass
end
```

After that I have run migration. Then in my rails console, I wrote that:

```
a = Child.new
a.name = "AAAA"
```

`name` is attribue that belongs to `AbstractModelClass`, console throws me `undefined method 'name'` error.

How can I make my child models inherit all attributes from my parent class?

I mostly programmed on Java and now I am very confused.

Comment: What's the basis of the claim that `name` is an attribute that belongs to `AbstractModelClass`?

Comment: I have run rails generator and applied attributes through it

Comment: So you generated `AbstractModelClass` with rails generator? But the attributes you passed into the generator don't have any meaning, since you made this class abstract (abstract classes don't use SQL table, but they can be inherited from). `ActiveRecord` attributes are fetched from the corresponding table's columns, so that's why you don't have `name` attribute.

Comment: So if I make my class abstract, its attributes will be useless for my child classes and I need to write all attributes for each of them again and again? This makes abstract classes in rails mostly...useless... only to keep  common `def` methods.

Comment: They are quite useful - they keep common methods. 
As I said: `ActiveRecord` 'attributes' (hint: they are setter/writer methods, since there's no direct equivalent to Java attributes in Ruby) are fetched from db columns. So: abstract class => no table => no attributes.

Comment: BTW if you want to have `name` and `name=` methods defined in all classes that inherit from your `AbstractModelClass`, why don't you use `attr_accessor :name`? Be aware though that this could cause problems if one of your model does have `name` column (I'm not sure what happens in this situation).

Comment: If I want to have some validation that is common for all child classes, or If I want to use gem like kaminari that has `paginates_per` in my abstract is that possible?

Comment: What you are using is called Single Table Inheritance. http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu don't mislead OP. It isn't STI.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu because it isn't single table?

Comment: Well... That's your opinion. Either way I think the OP will like to know about STI.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu it isn't my opinion, it's a fact. `abstract_class = true` indicates that the class doesn't use any table and that child classes use their own db tables. Sounds different than STI, doesn't it? Of course, showing STI mechanism to OP can be useful, but claiming that the abstract class is STI is, of course, misleading.

Comment: OK you are right. They are different things. Thanks for explaining it

Comment: OK if I use not abstract class and inherit from it. Is that Rails can't use JOINS or something like that to get data from separate tables or it can only keep all data of children in one table?